# How to get the value details from dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python

My dictionary is below

```
x={
    "contacts":{
        "101":{
            "email":"messi@gmail.com",
            "firstName":"Leo",
            "lastName":"Messi",
            "role":["Owner"]
        }
    }
}
```

- I need to extract the email if 'role' is "Owner"

Code is below

```
for i in (x.values()):
    for i,j in i.items():
        if 'Owner' in j['role']:
            print(j['email'])
```

Is there any way to extract without iteration over 2 times

Comment: If you can't be sure that you only have to look at the `x['contacts']` dict there can't be done very much.

Comment: Can there be multiple matchings in the role?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to extract all emails for "Owner" contacts

```
  emails = [contact_dict['email'] for contact_dict in x['contacts'].values() if 'Owner' in contact_dict['role']]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the data shown in the question you could simply do this:

```
x = {
    "contacts": {
        "101": {
            "email": "messi@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Leo",
            "lastName": "Messi",
            "role": ["Owner"]}
    }
}

if 'Owner' in x['contacts']['101']['role']:
    print(x['contacts']['101']['email'])
```

...although I suspect that what you really want is a list value associated with 'contacts'

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to yours that does what you mean is probably this:

```
x = {
    "contacts": {
        "101": {
            "email": "messi@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Leo",
            "lastName": "Messi",
            "role": ["Owner"]}
    }
}

for j in x['contacts'].values():
    if 'Owner' in j['role']:
        print(j['email'])
```

This code correctly prints `messi@gmail.com`.

My solution

- makes the small **assumption** that the target data is entirely within `x['contacts'].values()`,
- relies only on one straightforward loop, and
- uses the `items()` method, which returns a so-called view of the dictionary's (key, value)-pairs.

The answer by Viliam Popovec is structurally the same, but written in so-called "list comprehension" form.

Answer (score 0):

it could be done with pattern matching:

```
match x:
    case {"contacts": {"101": {"role": [*roles]}}} if "Owner" in roles:
        print(x["contacts"]["101"]["email"])
```

Answer (score -1):

There are packages in python that allow to do it more effectively, for example you can load your dictionary into a pandas dataframe, then you will be able to manipulate it better. With the basic python tools you are bound to loops or comprehensions.

Comment: Although it is possible, it would be more helpful if you can provide the code for OP instead of saying "you can do XYZ"